# Sharing Orchard CMS blog posts - overriding templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms

I'm using Orchard CMS and want to be able to show sharing links (think [AddThis.com](http://www.addthis.com) or [Shareaholic.com](http://www.shareaholic.com)) to blog posts on a website.

Before I start I realise there is a similar modules already present in the Orchard gallery but a, I couldn't get the module to work and b, I'd like to further my understanding of Orchard.

My thought originally was simply to add a new blog widget layer and to add a new HTML widget that contains the aforementioned sharing code. Trouble with this approach was;

1. The layer rule would force all of my blog pages to have to be under some common url i.e. using a layer rule of something like the following. Not necessarily a bad thing but something that could be missed when the client publishes a new post.

   url("~/blog*")
2. The sharing code contains empty html anchor elements that were getting stripped from the html when I saved in the Orchard editor.

I think #2 is down to the template used in my theme. I read a post from Bertrand Le Roy's blog about overriding templates which got me thinking. Can I just override the Orchard blog template and place the sharing code in there directly? Clearly this is less customisable in the future but I'm happy with that. I'm also thinking having fewer layers, moduels, widgets or whatever can't be a bad thing when considering Orchard performance and load times. I'd also now have my sharing icons on every blog post wherever it may be on the site.

Question is what is the view that I should override in this case? I tried editing the blog views in Modules\Orchard.Blogs\Views expecting to see some changes but I got nothing.

What would people suggest as the best way forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach IMHO is to add the code in one of two (or both) templates:

1. `Content-BlogPost.Summary.cshtml` when the blog post is shown in a list (you can copy the code from `/Core/Contents/Views/Content.Summary.cshtml`) and
2. `Content-BlogPost.Detail.cshtml` when the blog post is shown in a separate page (you can copy the code from `/Core/Contents/Views/Content.cshtml`)

Comment: Content-BlogPost.Summary.cshtml was what I was looking for. Out of interest, where did you learn what templates need to be overridden? Thanks.

Comment: If you enable designer tools shape tracing module, you can select any shape you want (in this case it's summary of blog post). In the `Shape` tab of selected shape you can see a list of available alternates with accompanied  link for creating that template. The functionality of this link is to take the content of currently active template (in your case `/Core/Contents/Views/Content.Summary.cshtml`) and paste it to the newly added template. You can find more info about shape tracing here - http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools